# Getting the most recent Modified Date older than 7 days per record with multiple dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the most recent record of an ID with a modified date older than 7 days however, results return all records for that id with records older than 7 days.

```
SELECT USERID
FROM [PROJ]
INNER JOIN [NOTES] ON [PROJ].id = [NOTES].projID
WHERE [PROJ.STATUS] = 'ACTIVE'
  AND [NOTES.MODIFIEDDATE] <= GETDATE() - 7
```

Returns:

```
project              userId        modifieddate
 1. 20190101              6           07/02/2019 *
 2. 20190101              6           07/01/2019
 3. 20190101              6           06/29/2019
 4. 20190102              7           07/04/2019 *
 5. 20190102              7           07/03/2019
```

*is what I expect returned.
This returns all records of all the ID's Notes with a modified date < = than 7 days I just want the most recent note(modified date) older than 7 Days.

Comment: Edit your question and (1) provide a database tag.  (2) qualify the column names so it is obvious where they come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a having clause

```
SELECT USERID
FROM [PROJ]
INNER JOIN [NOTES] ON [PROJ].id = [NOTES].projID
WHERE [PROJ.STATUS] = 'ACTIVE'
  AND [NOTES.MODIFIEDDATE] <= GETDATE() - 7 
GROUP BY USERID
HAVING MAX([NOTES.MODIFIEDDATE])
```

EDIT:
If you only want the most recent then I would get rid of the entirely

```
AND [NOTES.MODIFIEDDATE] <= GETDATE() - 7 

SELECT USERID
    FROM [PROJ]
    INNER JOIN [NOTES] ON [PROJ].id = [NOTES].projID
    WHERE [PROJ.STATUS] = 'ACTIVE'
    GROUP BY USERID
    HAVING MAX([NOTES.MODIFIEDDATE])
```

EDIT2:

```
SELECT USERID
    FROM [PROJ]
    INNER JOIN [NOTES] ON [PROJ].id = [NOTES].projID
    WHERE [PROJ.STATUS] = 'ACTIVE'
      AND [NOTES.MODIFIEDDATE] <= GETDATE() - 7 
    GROUP BY USERID, PROJECT
    HAVING MAX([NOTES.MODIFIEDDATE])
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for however, it returns the same list with all of the dates older than 7 days for each record. The idea here is to get the latest date of each project that has not been updated in seven days so we can send out an automated email. Any insight?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data to your question

Comment: Sample added as requested.

Comment: You will need to group by USERID, project